# To display the output on the app instead of terminal window in KIVY

Tags: python, kivy

I want to display my output on the app but I am only able to display it on the terminal window. I tried using label, ids, StringProperty but I am not unable to do it. Please help. Here is my code

https://del.dog/gilegnacay

Comment: Try to copy paste the code instead of posting an image

Comment: Could you please specify where and when you want what text to go where. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to help you but I am going to need some more information about the problem you are experiencing and what specifically you would like to happen.